# ObjectID is not defined. Cannot find object by id in Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb

I tried to google my simple problem, but cannot find answer.
I can't find any object by it's ObjectId.

```
db.user.find({_id:ObjectID("57fa0a15cf1e8c0e571e1a52")})
```

ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined

Why? What is wrong?

Comment: Did you try ObjectId()? I mean not 'ID' but 'Id'

Comment: oh, you are right.  BIG THANKS:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be ObjectId() not ObjectID()
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Answer (score 1):

**Solution :**

```
...collection("coll_name").find({"_id":new BSON.ObjectId("606aa80e929a618584d2758b")}));
```