# ObjectID not found

Tags: mongodb

I'm playing around with Mongo for the first and was following the [discussion on One-To-Many](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1?_ga=2.110139077.1575107493.1506329032-248653262.1506329018) relationship. They have an object with specific `_id` which has an `ObjectID` reference

```
> db.parts.findOne()
{
    _id : ObjectID('AAAA'),
    partno : '123-aff-456',
    name : '#4 grommet',
    qty: 94,
    cost: 0.94,
    price: 3.99
}
```

But I cannot seem to make the `ObjectID` work. (I understand its not a typo problem [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942102/objectid-is-not-defined-cannot-find-object-by-id-in-mongo-shell)). The [official page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#document-references) does not offer much guidance. How should I replicate the first tutorial please? I make it work with my own string as `_id` but why else are they using `ObjectID`, please?

Answer (score 0):

You stated it’s not a typo, then the Stack Overlow question you linked to has the exact typo you have. It’s `ObjectId` not `ObjectID`. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) for the documentation on `ObjectId`.

Comment: its not my typo, its from the [mongo db blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1?_ga=2.110139077.1575107493.1506329032-248653262.1506329018) so is there a typo and such a thing does not exist at all?]

Comment: You realize that’s not a tutorial though, right? It’s more of an overview with examples. Why they use `ObjectID` instead of `ObjectId` is beyond me, as there is nothing in the documentation about it.

Comment: well, that's why I'm asking because it is also beyond me :D

Comment: MongoDB has some really good documentation, and some great tutorials for beginners [here](https://resources.mongodb.com/getting-started-with-mongodb).